# Consumir web service desde c#

Tags: c#, webservice

Necesito consumir un web service desde .NET; tengo que conectarme al siguiente webservice:

[Web service](https://escuela.academi-cloud.net/ext_ws/integracion_escuela/actualizar_deuda_por_codigo)

**EndPoint:**   /ext_ws/integracion_escuela/actualizar_deuda_por_codigo

**Method:** POST

**Params:**

```
{api_key}: clave de autorización
{codigo}: código del estudiante
{valor_adeudado}: valor total adeudado
{valores_pendientes}: arreglo con el detalle de los valores pendientes de pago
```

**Request Ejemplo:**

```
{
 "api_key":  "############",
 "codigo":  "0885-E",
 "valor_adeudado": 120.65,
 "valores_pendientes":  [
  {
    "numero_factura" :  "001-001-0003875".
    "fecha" :  "01-02-2018",
    "monto_total" :  "120.65",
    "detalles" : [
      { "concepto" : "Pensión Enero", "valor" : "100.15" },
      { "concepto" : "Pensión Febrero", "valor" : "20.50" }
     ]
   }
 ]
}
```

**Resultado:**  Estructura JSON:

**resultado:** (true, false) indicador de resultado de la acción

**mensaje:** mensaje de la acción realizada

**Ejem. Resultado:**

```
{
“resultado”: true,
“mensaje”: “Registro Actualizado Correctamente”
}
```

Buscando algo de información tengo que consumirlo mediante la clase `HttpClient`

No se si alguien tiene algún ejemplo de como lo debería hacer o si ¿hay alguna otra forma mas efectiva de consumirlo?

Comment: que problemas tienes con HttpClient que no te funciona? pon el codigo

Comment: **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento debes modificar tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado o investigado, saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo hacerlo con [Programación asincrónica](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/hh191443(v=vs.120).aspx). Puede evitar cuellos de botella de rendimiento y mejorar la capacidad de respuesta total de la aplicación mediante la programación asincrónica.

En el siguiente ejemplo se realiza una comunicación con un ws(Web Service) para un objeto de la clase "pregunta". Si bien este metodo esta echo para retornar un objeto de esta misma clase, modifianddo el contenido de *"if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)"* puede ajustarlo a sus necesidades.

Lo que le recomiendo es siempre trabajar con objetos en su ws y vincularlo a proyecto mediaten la dll generada durante la publicación de su API.

Bibliotecas:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using API.Model;
using System.Configuration;
```

Código:

```
    string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["urlWS"] + "Pregunta/";


    public async Task<int> SavePregunta(Pregunta pregunta, bool isNewItem)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pregunta);
                var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var result = "";
                bool ok = false;
                HttpResponseMessage response = null;

                if (isNewItem)
                {
                    response = await client.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    response = await client.PutAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

                    result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    pregunta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Pregunta>(result);

                }

                return pregunta;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Espero que le sirva. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

aunque la pregunta es muy general creo que podria ayudarte segun veo tu comunicación va a ser usando json  (es una forma de representar una clase en solo texto) para ello te recomiendo estas bibliotecas:
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json
con esta herramienta puedes sacar una clase del "paquete" ejemplo http://json2csharp.com
trata de hacer algo así para generar el post:

```
public override bool Post(TModel model) //cambia el objeto para que sea tu clase
{
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request;
            Url = @"";//pones aqui la direccion web
            request = WebRequest.Create(Url) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Timeout = 10 * 1000;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }
            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //si el post falla queda aqui
        }
        return false;
    }
```