# Error al deserializar cadena JSON en Object Class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

En mi servidor hago esto :

```
 [HttpGet]
        public string GetSeleccionarTodasFilasTabla(string NombreTabla, string Version)
        {
            string resultado = string.Empty;
            Engine.EngineDb FuncionDb = new Engine.EngineDb();          
            int permiso = FuncionDb.PermisoSync(Version);
            if (permiso < 1)
            {
                return resultado = Engine.EngineData.SyncNoPermitida;
            }
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = FuncionDb.SeleccionarTodasFilasTabla(NombreTabla);
            if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                resultado = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented);
            }
            else
            {
                resultado = Engine.EngineData.NoHayFilas;
            }
            return resultado;
        }
```

Me devuelve una cadena como esta

```
"[\r\n  {\r\n  \"IdAbono\": 1,\r\n    \"Nombre\": \"No abona\"\r\n  },
\r\n  {\r\n    \"IdAbono\": 2,\r\n    \"Nombre\": \"Abono orgánico\"\r\n  },
\r\n  {\r\n    \"IdAbono\": 3,\r\n    \"Nombre\": \"Fertilizante químico\"\r\n  },
\r\n  {\r\n    \"IdAbono\": 4,\r\n    \"Nombre\": \"Combinación\"\r\n  }\r\n]"
```

en mi aplicacion tengo esto :

```
private void ClientGetTablaAbono(string RequestURI)
        {
            string resultado = string.Empty;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:52143/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response = client.GetAsync(RequestURI).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                resultado = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                List<Abono> TAbono = new List<Abono>();

                //AQUI EL ERROR
                TAbono = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Abono>>(resultado);
            }
            else
            {
                resultado = response.IsSuccessStatusCode.ToString();
                richTextBox1.Text = resultado;
            }
        }
```

Mi Clase Abono es esta :

```
  public class Abono
        {
            public int IdAbono { get; set; }

            public string Nombre { get; set; }
        }
```

ERROR

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value "[
  {
    "IdAbono": 1,
    "Nombre": "No abona"
  },
  {
    "IdAbono": 2,
    "Nombre": "Abono orgánico"
  },
  {
    "IdAbono": 3,
    "Nombre": "Fertilizante químico"
  },
  {
    "IdAbono": 4,
    "Nombre": "Combinación"
  }
]" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ApiRestConsumer.Form2+Abono]'. Path '', line 1, position 308.'

ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ApiRestConsumer.Form2+Abono].
```

Comment: Intenta agregarle delante de la declaración de la clase Abono esto [JsonObject]

Comment: El código de deserializar el resultado no tiene nada mal,así que el problema debe estar en la otra parte del código. ¿Estás seguro de que estás obteniendo el resultado correcto del servidor? Asegúrate de que la cadena que devuelve el servidor es el valor que obtienes en tu variable `resultado`.

Comment: Siii estoy seguro ...de hecho fijate en mi pregunta esta hasta la cadena que devuelvo

Comment: Podrá ser problema de la forma en que te retorna los datos? Me refiero a **\r\n** y el resto? Yo probé tu código con tu `json` y me funciono perfecto... Deberías probar reemplazando esos caracteres antes de ejecutar `ReadAsStringAsync()`

Comment: Hola Efrain, te dejo un link de una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/142973/consumir-web-service-desde-c/191143#191143) donde explico como hacerlo. Ahí también vas a ver como puedes hacerlo con una conexión async que es lo mas recomendado. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer el tema está en la forma en que el server te está devolviendo la data. Mi idea es que como estás serializando el datatable usando el `JsonConvert` luego el api puede estar efectuando una segunda serialización y por tanto el json que estás recibiendo no es exactamente deserializable, al menos no sin antes reversar la primera serialización.

### Deserializar primero a string.

En la línea antes de deserializar la respuesta, haz una primera deserialización a string.

```
List<Abono> TAbono = new List<Abono>();

//Deserializamos primero a string. 
resultado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(resultado);

//AQUI EL ERROR (AHORA DEBERIA FUNCIONAR CORRECTAMENTE)
TAbono = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Abono>>(resultado);
```

### ¿Qué hacer luego? (Si funciona el primer punto)

Si el punto anterior funciona, quiere decir que tu server está enviando la data no de la mejor manera posible. Te recomendaría hacer algunos ajustes pero esperemos a ver si es esto en definitiva.

No sé exactamente qué variante de **web api** tienes (si es net core, o web api 2.x u otra). Pero en cualquier caso la respuesta del api debería ser un json string y no un json string serializado a string.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias  ..Karel Tamaño...funciono a la perfeccion